# When should I call save() on an instance of a domain object in Grails?

Tags: grails, persistence

From what I've read, `save()` informs the persistence context that an instance should be saved or updated.  However, I have methods in a service that change the property of a domain instance without calling `save()` and the change appears instantly in my database, no problem.

Is the `save()` method just a more secure way of knowing that a domain instance will be updated after making a change (and catching errors with the failOnError mapping)? Should it be used EVERY time I change a domain instance's properties or is that overdoing it?

Comment: Is the database being instantly updated or is your hibernate cache being instantly updated?

Comment: The MySql database that I am using is being updated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you create a new instance of a domain class, then a `.save()` call will tell the underlying Hibernate layer to persist the new object to the database.  Without the `.save()` it won't be persisted to the database.

If you retrieve an object via a `.get(myId)`, then any changes will be automatically persisted to the database at the end of the underlying transaction because Hibernate sees the object as "dirty".  The end of a transaction is at the end of a method call to a transactional service or end of a request for controllers.  You can call `.save()` if you want in these instances, but it isn't necessary.  It does provide easy access to flushing Hibernate via `.save(flush:true)` or the `failOnError` usage for validation.

Comment: I use a .findBy() to retrieve the object but I assume that it has the same "save-at-the-end-of-the-method" effect as a .get.

Comment: Yes, the persist occurs for any method of retrieving an existing object, unless it is a read-only retrieval like `.read()`.

Comment: Leveraging the validation is probably one of the most common usages of `save()` outside of persisting a new instance.

Comment: Save is also not necessary if A and B are in a relationship and you do B.addTo(A), the A will be saved anyway, even if you didn't call save on it

Answer (score 0):

In addition to schmolly159 answer, I'll just add that you do not need to use save also when the entity you had created is being added to some other entity that already exists in the db (has its own id).

From Grails in Action book:

> Notice that we have to call save() on the User object to persist it in the database B. Once the User is attached to the database, though, any additions we make to its object graph (like adding new Post objects via addToPosts() C) are automatically persisted. For this reason, we don’t need to call save() on each Post we create